# SFINAE remove function from overload set if a free function does / does not exist

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the canonical way to remove a template function from the overload set if a particular free function does not exist. So I have a function

```
template <typename T> void foo( T t )
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

and I want to remove this from the overload set if a free function taking a parameter of type T, say

```
bar( T )
```

does not exist.

Also how about the inverse remove a function from the overload if a free function does exist. So remove the function foo above if the function bar does exist?

Answer (score 4):

Simple expressions like that one can be easily SFINAE'd with `decltype`:

```
template <typename T>
auto foo( T t ) -> decltype(bar(t), void())
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to prevent implicit conversions with this technique? *(i.e. check if `bar(t)` takes exactly a `float`, where `t` is a `double` that would get implicitly converted during a normal call)*

Comment: @VittorioRomeo maybe [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/P5XjjcsuNMG7BuCS) would do the trick? Or even better [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/IVY9AD5ZHeTN0f5a)?

Answer (score 2):

```
namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class Z, class, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply:std::false_type{};
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, std::void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>:std::true_type{};
};
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply = details::can_apply<Z, void, Ts...>;

template<class T>
using bar_r = decltype( bar( std::declval<T>() ) );

template<class T>
using can_bar = can_apply<bar_r, T>;
```

this gives us a trait `can_bar` which is `true` iff `bar(t)` is a valid expression.

```
template<class T>
  std::enable_if_t< can_bar<T>{}, int> =0
>
void foo( T t ) {}
```

which has the advantage that the SFINAE does not mess up the `foo` function apparent signature.  The inverse is easy:

```
template<class T>
  std::enable_if_t< !can_bar<T>{}, int> =0
>
void foo( T t ) {}
```

another advantage of this technique.

Note that you might want to `can_bar<T&>` instead of `T` if you are calling it in an lvalue context instead of forwarding it.

---

Some of the above is beyond C++11.

It uses a C++14 feature of `enable_if_t`.  Replace `enable_if_t<blah>` with `typename enable_if<blah>::type` in C++11, or write your own `enable_if_t`.

It also uses a C++14 feature of `std::void_t`.

```
template<class...>struct voider{using type=void;};
template<class...Ts>using void_t = typename voider<Ts...>::type;
```

to write it in C++11.

`is_detected`, which on track for C++20, is similar to `can_apply` above.

Comment: That's awesome, worked for me on VS 2015. So what would this look like once std::is_detected is available?

Comment: @goneskiing `decltype` cannot safely be used for SFINAE on VS, even indirectly.  It may work, but innocuous changes can break it.  On VS2015, relying on SFINAE is dangerous in my experience, unless you can use C++03 level SFINAE.  `is_detected` would look much like `can_apply`; I would have to look up the exact syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename T, typename = decltype( bar( std::declval<T>() ), void() ) >
void foo( T t )
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: @Jarod42 Maybe `template <typename T, typename... Args, typename = decltype( bar( std::declval<T>() ), void() ) > void foo(T) {}` could work better in this terms...?